# Elastic search query with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am facing an issue with es query with python.
Query I am using is :

```
response = es_host.search(index=f"<index>,
                                   query={
                                       "aggs": {"0": {"terms": {"field": "parsed_log.requestPath.keyword",
                                                                         "order": {"_count": "desc"},
                                                                         "size": 10000}}}, "size": 0,
                                                "script_fields": {},
                                                "stored_fields": ["*"], "runtime_mappings": {},
                                                "query": {"bool": {"must": [],
                                                                   "filter": [{"match_phrase": {
                                                                       "parsed_log.responseStatusCode": 200}},
                                                                              {"range": {"log-time": {
                                                                                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
                                                                                  "gte": "2023-07-20T03:30:00.000Z",
                                                                                  "lte": "2023-07-21T03:30:00.000Z"}}}],
                                                                   "should": [], "must_not": []}}})
```

gives the following error: elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'unknown query [aggs]')

Can someone let me know whats happening here also the solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace query to body.
Example:

```
es_host.search(index="index_name", body={ ... })
```

Comment: when i use the above method , i get a warning that says: DeprecationWarning: The 'body' parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instead use individual parameters.